# python regular expression

Tags: python

I am newbie to python. I have an array of words and each word has to be checked to see whether it contains any special characters or digits. If it contains so then i have to skip that word. How should i do this?

Comment: How about providing some example words, the special characters you want to check for, and what you want the output to look like. We may be good, but we're programmers not mind readers.

Comment: Also, this sounds like it could be a homework problem. If it is please tag it as such.

Comment: hello must be accepted, hello1 must not be accepted, ?hello2 must not be accepted....i.e simply stated the words that do not contain any special characters or numbers must be accepted

Comment: if u feel it to be a homework problem then please dont answer it...i just aksed for help..thats it

Comment: So you mean any words with non-alphabetic characters must be discarded from the array (by which I assume you mean a Python list)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My reading of the problem is that you want to discard any words that contain non-alphabetical characters. Try the following:

```
>>> array = ['hello', 'hello2', '?hello', '?hello2']
>>> filtered = filter(str.isalpha, array)
>>> print filtered
['hello']
```

You could also write it as a list comprehension:

```
>>> filtered = [word for word in array if word.isalpha()]
>>> print filtered
['hello']
```

Answer (score 4):

Does it have to be a regular expression?  If not, you can use the [isalpha()](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=isalpha#str.isalpha) string method.

Answer (score 1):

If there are only a few characters you want to exclude then use a blacklist, otherwise use a white list.

```
import string
abadword="""aaaa
bbbbb"""
words=["oneGoodWord", "a,bc",abadword, "xx\n",'123',"gone", "tab    tab", "theEnd.","anotherGoodWord"]

bad=list(string.punctuation) #string.punctuation='!"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~'
bad+=['\n','\t','1'] #add some more characters you don't want
bad+=['one'] #this is redundant as in function skip set(word) becomes a set of word's characters. 'one' cannot match a character.

print bad #bad = ['!', '"', '#', '$', '%', '&', "'", '(', ')', '*', '+', ',', '-', '.', '/', ':', ';', '<', '=', '>', '?', '@', '[', '\\', ']', '^', '_', '`', '{', '|', '}', '~', '\n', '\t', '1', 'one']

bad=set(bad)

def skip(word):
    return len(set(word) & bad)==0 #word has no characters in common with bad word

print "good words:"
print filter(skip,words) #prints ['oneGoodWord', 'gone', 'anotherGoodWord']
```